# NSS error -8178 when using entrust certificate on centos

Tags: php, curl, openssl, centos, ca

Hi I have created xero entrust certificate using firefox and seperated private and public certificates with the help of [this](http://developer.xero.com/documentation/getting-started/partner-applications/) link and uploaded it on my centos server but when I am running my xero application on server, I am getting the following error

```
* About to connect() to api-partner.network.xero.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 198.61.252.64... * connected
* Connected to api-partner.network.xero.com (198.61.252.64) port 443 (#0)
* warning: ignoring unsupported value (1) of ssl.verifyhost
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* Unable to load client key -8178.
* NSS error -8178
* Closing connection #0
```

Can anyone help to sort this out?